# How to collapse Foundation's xy-grid-layout cells outer gutters?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Trying to get my head around building Foundation's XY Grid semantically (https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html#building-semantically).

Think I've got most of it figured out minus a nested xy-grid-layout within a xy-grid.

[image]

My goal is to have the outer gutters on the outer cells to collapse so the Block Grid is flush with the main content cell:

[image]

Here's what I've got so far:

```
.fr_container {
  @include xy-grid-container;
}

.fr_grid {
  @include xy-grid;
  background-color: $light-gray;
}

.fr_main {
  @include xy-cell();
  @include flex-order(2);
  background-color: $medium-gray;

  @include breakpoint(medium) {
    @include xy-cell(9);
    @include flex-order(1);
  }
}

.fr_sidebar {
  @include xy-cell();
  @include flex-order(1);
  background-color: $medium-gray;

  @include breakpoint(medium) {
    @include xy-cell(3);
    @include flex-order(2);
  }
}

.fr_full {
  @include xy-cell();
}

.fr_gallery {
  @include xy-grid;
  @include xy-grid-layout(3, '.fr_gallery-item', true, $grid-margin-gutters, margin, right left top bottom, false);
  background-color: $dark-gray;
}

.fr_gallery-item {
  background-color: $black;
  border: rem-calc(1) dashed $white;
  color: $white;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="fr_container">
  <h3>Grid Container</h3>
  <div class="fr_grid">
    <h3 class="fr_full">Grid</h3>
    <div class="fr_main">
      <h3>Main Content</h3>
      <h4>Block Grid</h4>
      <div class="fr_gallery">
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">1</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">2</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">3</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">4</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">5</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">6</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">7</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">8</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">9</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">10</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">11</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">12</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">13</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">14</div>
        <div class="fr_gallery-item">15</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fr_sidebar">
      <h3>Sidebar</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well Ben, to collapse the outer margin, perhaps all you need to do is add this margin override ?

```css
.fr_container {
  @include xy-grid-container;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The margin isn't on that container, it's on the individual cells.